# Setting minHeight of AppBarLayout's child programmatically

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

What I want to achieve is something similar to an CollapsingToolbar. I've got the below layout for my activity.

The item inside the `AppBarLayout` can be of variable height. Therefore I was trying to set `minHeight` of the item programmatically, from within the `onPreDraw()` method of `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`.

However setting the minHeight programmatically does not seem to have any effect. The AppBarLayout does scroll off the screen completely. Setting the minHeight directly inside the XML yields the expected result and stops the AppBarLayout from scrolling off screen.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible to set the minHeight programmatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/header" >
            // Header of variable height
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/rv_items"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        clContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                clContent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                int minHeight = calculateMinHeight();
                clHeader.setMinHeight(minHeight);

                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
appBarLayout.setMinimumHeight(100);

Have you tried this?

Comment: Yeah, already tried setting minHeight to the AppBarLayout, without success

Comment: Dunno what I did yesterday, was sure I tried setting minHeight to the AppBarLayout, but didn't work. But using View.setMinimumHeight() did the trick. As it looks, ConstraintLayout has its own mMinHeight field, NOT inheriting from View, which is set by using ConstraintLayout.setMinHeight()

Answer (score 1):

Try to use setMinimumHeight(minHeight) instead - this should solve the problem.